# Off by one issue with concatenating strings

Tags: python

Say I have a problem where I have to scan a list to find all instances of words that begin with `foo` but I have no idea how many there might be and the output has to be in the format `<out1, out2, etc..>`

Currently I've been doing:

```
toReturn = '<'
toReturn += [word in word for mylonglist if word.startswith('foo') + ', ']
toReturn = toReturn[:-2] + '>'
print toReturn
```

is there a cleaner way to do this? thanks!

Comment: Your existing code doesn't actually work. As written, you're adding a list to a string; you must have a `''.join(…)` or something else in there. Also, you're trying to add the `', '` to a bool, not to a string, and even if that were legal, you're doing that in the `if` clause, which can't affect the value that goes into the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `join` to specify a delimiter to inject between elements of a sequence and return a `string`. The you can use `format` to add the `'<'` and `'>'` to the ends.

```
>>> myList = ['foobar', 'footest', 'not', 'test', 'foothing']
>>> '<{}>'.format(', '.join(i for i in myList if i.startswith('foo')))
'<foobar, footest, foothing>'
```

Comment: Beat me to it tho might be worth noting that if it's python 2.7 I believe you have to use {0} instead of {}.

Comment: @user2097159: No, that's only in 2.6 (and 3.0); 2.7 (and 3.1+) have `{}`.